# kube-apiserver not coming up after adding --admission-control-config-file flag

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
root@ubuntu151:~# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.8", GitCommit:"9f2892aab98fe339f3bd70e3c470144299398ace", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-13T16:12:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.10", GitCommit:"62876fc6d93e891aa7fbe19771e6a6c03773b0f7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-15T01:43:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

My admission webhooks require authentication so I'm restarting the apiserver by specifying the location of the admission control configuration file via the `--admission-control-config-file` flag. Doing as:

```
root@ubuntu151:~# vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
...
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
     - --admission-control-config-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kube-AdmissionConfiguration.yaml
...
```

```
root@ubuntu151:~# vi /var/lib/kubernetes/kube-AdmissionConfiguration.yaml

apiVersion: apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1
kind: AdmissionConfiguration
plugins:
- name: ValidatingAdmissionWebhook
  configuration:
    apiVersion: apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1
    kind: WebhookAdmissionConfiguration
    kubeConfigFile: /var/lib/kubernetes/kube-config.yaml
- name: MutatingAdmissionWebhook
  configuration:
    apiVersion: apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1
    kind: WebhookAdmissionConfiguration
    kubeConfigFile: /var/lib/kubernetes/kube-config.yaml
```

kubeConfigFile: /var/lib/kubernetes/kube-config.yaml is the file I copied from ~/.kube/config

Now my kube-apiserver is not coming up .

Please help !

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Have you checked its logs?

Comment: In journalctl -full output i can only get below regarding kube-apiserver. 
`skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver" with CrashLoopBackOff:`

Comment: What about `kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-apiserver-minikube` ?

Comment: Its a pre-production grade servers, I'm used kubeadm to setup my cluster so kube-apiserver runs as a pod which is not coming up so i can't get the logs using `kubectl logs...`

Comment: _"I'm used kubeadm to setup my cluster so kube-apiserver runs as a pod which is not coming up"_ - so why have you added `minikube` tag to your question ? If your cluster was set up using **kubeadm**, it has nothing to do with **minikube** so please remove any irrelevant tags. If your `kube-apiserver` is running as a `Pod` and enters `CrashLoopBackOff` state, there should be some info why it's happening. If it doesn't show any logs, you can still `kubectl describe` it, to obtain some details on what's going on there (see `Events` section).